# WordPress dashboard options disappeared after using WP Reset plugin

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

**I am using 1&1 IONOS hosting and i used one-click-WordPress-install option**

I used WP reset plugin to get back default settings and cleaning up demo data previously installed. I got an error that some files are missing but the page refreshed before i could read all of it. After i logged in back to wp-admin, the dashboard is now clean. No options (Appearance, Pages, Posts etc) can be seen on left menu.

[image: This is image of the dashboard after i signed in back]

I checked the hosting files if anything got deleted but the folders like wp-content, wp-include are all there. I don't know what seems to be missing.

[image: Website folder on hosting]

Screenshot from **phpmyadmin** for all the tables that still exist there :

[image]

Comment: It seems that you are not an admin anymore ... juste a subscriber. Try this : https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/

Comment: @AlexVand it worked man!! please post it as an answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are **not an admin anymore** ... just a **subscriber**. Try to create a new admin user within your database.

Tutorial to do that:

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/

MySQL code from the tutorial ( Replace needed values with yours )

```
INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('4', 'demo', MD5('demo'), 'Your Name', 'test@yourdomain.com', 'http://www.test.com/', '2011-06-07 00:00:00', '', '0', 'Your Name');


INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');


INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```